# Updating values in an iPhone plist

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an app that I want the user to be able to set some default.  They are stored in .plist file.

On app Launch it checks for the file in Documents, and if it doesn't find it, it copies the bundled file.

I can read the values from the plist in the Documents, but if I try and update them in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

then

```
NSMutableDictionary* updateVal=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
```

Crashes the app with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" but only if the values have changed.

Full Code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
NNSMutableDictionary* updateVal=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];

NSNumber* defWidthSet = defaultWidthDel;
NSNumber* defAspectSet = defaultAspectDel;

[updateVal setObject:defWidthSet forKey:@"defaultWidth"];
[updateVal setObject:defAspectSet forKey:@"defaultAspect"];
[updateVal writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];
[updateVal release];
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

***EDIT:***

Got it Working...

New Code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* updateVal=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];

NSNumber* defWidthSet = defaultWidthDel;
NSNumber* defAspectSet = defaultAspectDel;

[updateVal setObject:defWidthSet forKey:@"defaultWidth"];
[updateVal setObject:defAspectSet forKey:@"defaultAspect"];
[updateVal writeToFile:docPath atomically:NO];
[updateVal release];
```

Can anyone tell me what was wrong about the first way I was doing it?

Comment: Just a guess but the atomic writing may have failed because the app was going into the background before the process was complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* updateVal=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
NSNumber* defWidthSet = defaultWidthDel;
NSNumber* defAspectSet = defaultAspectDel;
[updateVal setObject:defWidthSet forKey:@"defaultWidth"];
[updateVal setObject:defAspectSet forKey:@"defaultAspect"];
[updateVal writeToFile:docPath atomically:NO];
[updateVal release];
```